# C# Loading GPS data to a Map

Tags: c#, google-maps, gps, maps

I have vehicles that report back to the home office that send along GPS coordinates (Longitude and Lattitude) whenever they report home. I'd like to be able to take those coordinates, and have a map pop up with a little marker showing the coordinates of the latest GPS coordinates. A line connecting all of them would be extra nice.

Is there an API or something that I can use to integrate a map into my program?

I am currently using VS2013 with C# .NET 3.5 for a Desktop application.

I've already looked around and I've only seen things about hooking up GPS serial com ports or phone.

Comment: Here is this API for Google Maps but it isn't an integrated one so you should download the it. Also it is designed for .NET 3.5 so it should work
https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

Comment: Thank you very much! If you post this as an answer, I'll add accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is this API for Google Maps but it isn't an integrated one so you should download the it. Also it is designed for .NET 3.5 so it should work:  github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

You should be able to download it from Git directly or from Nuget package manager.